# Drupal Email Verfication

Tags: 7, emails

How to verify email of registered users and only verified users are allowed to login.
For that I have set up status of user to 'Blocked' immediately after registration so that they can't login.
But when I access verification link I am getting 'Access Denied' error.
How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using any contrib/custom  module to enhance registration process?

Answer (score 2):

Admin -> Config -> People -> Account settings

Under "Registration and cancellation", select "Visitors, but administrator approval is required".

Comment: I have tried your solution. But I am still getting access denied

Comment: "Administer approval is required" - did an administrator approve the account?

Comment: Sorry. I have customized email verification callback and added a custom table for checking whether the user is verified by mail.